# Extract text between two text strings from webpage with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There's lots out there on BeautifulSoup, but I can't find anything that answers this... I want to extract the text between two bits of html by specifying the bit of text before and after in the code. I can do this with Outwit Python module but need to use BeautifulSoup this time...

The bit of the pages I want is the usernames below:

```
<a class="generic_class" href="/people/username">
```

So, I want to specify beautifulsoup to scrape the username by telling it to look for

> 'a class="generic_class" href="/people/'

before the bit to scrape and stop after

> '"'

I then want it to do this in a loop of urls from a csv (this already works) and then append the results line by line to a new csv (this bit probably doesn't work):

```
for row in url_reader:
    url = row[0]
    page = br.open(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
    user = soup.findAll('<a class="generic_class" href="/people/') # this is the line where the code that works should go! Obviously this bit does nothing as it doesn't extract what comes after, stopping at the closing quotation mark for the end of the href.
    page.append.user(output_file) # not sure if this is right?!
```

Obviously, in an ideal world, I'd put this in an if/else to if (finds "page not found") and else (do the thing above) to deal with urls that don't work, but I'll work the error handling in once I can actually make the thing work! That's my priority now...

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't you just extract "href" attribute value and parse that?

```
usernames = []

for anchor in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'generic_class'}):
    usernames.append(anchor['href'].split('/')[-1])

with open('usernames.csv', 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for username in usernames:
        writer.writerow([username])
```

This is just a simple example, I recommend making some additional validation etc.

Comment: That gives me AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Not sure where did you get that error from, I used this to test it:

html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="generic_class" href="/people/username1"></li>
    <li><a href="/people/username2"></li>
    <li><a class="generic_class" href="/people/username3"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
"""

which line that error comes from?

Comment: Traceback says the first line of your suggested answer :(

Comment: for attr, matchAgainst in self.attrs.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Sorry I have corrected my answer. I did typo and got set instead of a dict, not sure why but it did work on my machine :)  {'class', 'generic_class'} -> {'class': 'generic_class'}

Comment: Fantastic - this works and now spits out the usernames - thanks! May I ask if you can complete the answer by suggesting the command to append to my output_file ? output_file = 'output.csv'

Comment: Updated my answer - I would need more requirements to be more explicit but this should do what you need :)

Comment: Great! Works! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function in the `href` attribute:

```
def start_with_people(href):
    return href and href.startswith('/people/')

a_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_='generic_class', href=start_with_people)
```

This will return all the `<a>` tags which have an href starting with `/people/`.

Once you have these anchor tags :

1. you can loop over it
2. get the `href` value
3. split it and get the username

Comment: This gives me an error: a_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_='generic_class', href=start_with_people)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: If I change it to 'soup.findAll' then it doesn't error, but it doesn't find anything either.

Comment: Which version do you have?